# Python の input()で改行をさせない方法

Tags: python, python3

Python3でinput()で入力した時に改行をさせない方法はありますか。

入力を3とした時、希望する出力結果は以下のような感じです。

```
  | x | *2 | *4 |
a | 3 |  6 | 12 |
```

現状は以下のようになってしまいます。

```
  | x | *2 | *4 |
a | 3
 |  6 | 12 |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

まず、input() が改行を出力しているわけではなく、ユーザが改行を入力しているものを端末がエコー(ユーザが入力した内容を確認できるように出力)しているため、改行が発生します。

そのため端末の設定を変更することでしか、ユーザの改行に対して出力される改行を抑止することはできません。

以下のコードは termios モジュールをサポートしている環境であればそれっぽい動作をするかと思います。(Windows 版 Python や IDLE では動作しません。 Windows 上の cygwin 版の Python なら動作するかと思います）

```
import termios
import sys
import os

class KeyScanner:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.fno = sys.stdin.fileno()

        # backup current settings
        self.termattr_backup = termios.tcgetattr(self.fno)

        new_attr = termios.tcgetattr(self.fno)
        new_attr[3] &= ~termios.ECHO # no echo
        new_attr[3] &= ~termios.ICANON # no canonical
        termios.tcsetattr(self.fno, termios.TCSADRAIN, new_attr)

        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        # restore old settings
        termios.tcsetattr(self.fno, termios.TCSANOW, self.termattr_backup)

    def readInt(self):
        number_text = ''

        c = sys.stdin.read(1)
        while True:
            if c == '\n':
                break
            elif c.isdigit():
                sys.stdout.write(c)
                sys.stdout.flush()
                number_text += c
            c = sys.stdin.read(1)

        if number_text.isdigit():
            return int(number_text)
        else:
            return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with KeyScanner() as scanner: 
        print("  | x | *2 | *4 |")
        print("a | ", end='', flush=True)
        x = scanner.readInt()
        if x:
            print(" | {:>2} | {:>2} |".format(x*2, x*4))
        else:
            print("\nNO INPUT ERROR!")
```

Comment: 同じような方法として、標準ライブラリではなさそうですが、 getch() とか、redachar() という方法もあるようです。これだと、Windowsでも OK でしょうか。　ただ、入力がエコーされなさそうなので、その対応が必要かと。

Comment: msvcrt の getch() だと今度は Windows のコンソール環境でしか動きませんね。元質問者の方が OS 環境くらい書いてくれればよいのですが…

Comment: 検索して見つけたここ (http://azwoo.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/01/07/185413) にあるコードだと、unixも対応してるみたいです。 他はどうなのでしょうか。 まあ、getch() のネーミングは Window(DOS) 由来みたいですが。 なお、上記の redachar() --> readchar() の間違い。

Comment: ああ、windows では msvcrt の getch() を使って Unix では termios を使うように作られたラッパクラスを作った人がいるのですね～。そうであればラッパライブラリのURLを書かないと伝わらないかと思います。(「getch()」という名前があまりにもありふれた名前のため)

Comment: 環境はOSX(PyCharm)でした。
色々と考察ありがとうございます。コンソールですとどこかしらで制限がでてしまうみたいですね。
GUIで対処してみたいと思います。お手数おかけしましたm(_ _)m

Answer (score 2):

`input()` ではなく `sys.stdin.read()` を用いると EOF 文字 (`^D`; Ctrl + d) で終端を指定できます．

具体的には

```
import sys

print('  | x | *2 | *4 |\na | ', end='')
x = int(sys.stdin.read())
print(' | {:>2} | {:>2} |'.format(x*2, x*4))
```

を実行して，`3^D^D` を入力すると期待する出力になると思います．

参考：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871100/python-3-how-to-ignore-line-breaks-when-using-input

Answer (score 0):

`input()`で受け取った結果に余計な改行が含まれているのが問題であれば、`strip()`メソッドで取り除いてやるのが良さそうです(他の言語であれば`chop`に相当)。

引数なしで呼び出すと空白と改行を、引数に文字群を与えるとその文字群に該当する文字をすべて取り除きます。`strip()`は文字の両端(先頭と末尾)、`lstrip()`は文字の先頭、`rstrip()`は文字の末尾を対象にして処理を行います。

```
>>> "  ABC123  ".strip()
'ABC123'
>>> "  ABC123  \n".strip()
'ABC123'
```

参考
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/climpy/20090904/1252673537